# Como impedir o usuário de fazer alterarações no input?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um `input` em um formulário, porém ele não deve ter seu valor alterado:

```
<input type="text" name="pais" value="">
```

Como posso impedir que o valor seja alterado?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Pais: <input type="text" name="pais" value=""><br>
  Estado: <input type="text" name="estado" value=""><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Colocando a propriedade [readonly](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)?

Comment: Use readonly="true"

Comment: pq foi colocado as tags PHP e javascript ? vc qer uma solução com essas linguagens ? ou o readonly ja basta ?

Comment: poderia ter uma solução em php e javascript também !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o atributo `readonly` do elemento `input` para isso:

```
<input type="text" name="pais" value="" readonly />
```

Answer (score 2):

As outras respostas já contemplam o que foi pedido, entretanto gostaria de deixar uma alternativa utilizando JavaScript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('input-disabled').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('input-readonly').readOnly = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-disabled">
<input type="text" id="input-readonly">
```

Através do *onload*, quanto a página carregar o seu conteúdo, crio uma função para pegar o elemento com id igual a `input-disabled` e adicionar o atributo `:disabled` como verdadeiro. O mesmo vale para o elemento com id igual a `input-readonly`, o qual adiciono o atributo `:readOnly` como verdadeiro.

Já sobre o `:disabled` e `:readonly`:

- *Disabled* não passa o valor para o fomulário, além de não poder editar.
- *Readonly* envia o valor para o formulário e também não pode editar.